# Multiple Condition with Groupby

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting error wih following code, "Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.
"

```
SELECT [sddoc],
  [Soldtopt],
  [tradingname],
  [DlvDate],
  SUM(try_cast(Netvalue AS FLOAT)) AS Netvalue,
  COUNT(DISTINCT SDDoc) AS Salesdoc ,
  COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN Netvalue = '0'
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS ZeroValue ,
  COUNT(DISTINCT SDDoc) - COUNT(DISTINCT
  CASE
    WHEN Netvalue = '0'
    THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
  END) AS Result
FROM d1
WHERE dlvdate='25.01.2017'
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN SUM(try_cast(Netvalue AS FLOAT)) = 0
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT SDDoc)             = 1
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT
      CASE
        WHEN Netvalue = '0'
        THEN 1
        ELSE NULL
      END) = 1
    THEN [sddoc]
  END,
  Soldtopt,
  tradingname,
  DlvDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SUM or COUNT (aggregates) in the GROUP BY clause.  Aggregate values must be calculated after groups are defined.

Also, your CASE lacks an ELSE clause.

Comment: In addition you have fields in your SELECT that are neither aggregated nor grouped.